# Best way to run python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 which comes with python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.7, backport

I would like to avoid backports, they always seem to mess up my packages.

So I was thinking tools like conda / virtualenv / maybe even docker can help. What's the most simple / cleanest way to work with python 3.7 on my system?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Docker is fine and so is virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper.

Pass in the `-p` to the binary if you're working with a virtual environment.